automatically batch conversion of local file links to sharepoint links?
Is there a method, or an efficient approach of performing an conversion of local file link (to other files) to sharepoint (MSTeams sites) links?
Context:
a co-worker has an Excel file on a local harddisk. This Excel file contains 400+ links to other files stored locally (Word files, PDF files).
Now, she want to migrate all her files to an MSTeams (Sharepoint) site. A small test concludes us that these local file links are not valid when the files are moved to Sharepoint (MSTeams).
I am looking for an efficient solution. Something like a bulk conversion of all the links in the Excel file. While maintaining all other aspects of the Excel file. (only conversion of the links). Rather than having to change all the 400+ links manually -> a huge work.
Please advice.
Thanks,
Mathijs

I don't think this is even possible. Only way I can think of is manually replacing it with shared links created directly from sharepoint. One way would be, if only she needs access, is to move all files to sharepoint and search/replace part of the path so its her local sharepoint again. But this can break easily.
